# BixBy: singular plural utterances doesn't give exact result

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

User: Show me my recommendation (added into training)
BixBy: shows some results

user: Show me my recommendations (Not added into training)
BixBy: Custom error message

Both utterances are the same but still one is giving me the result and another one is not. Please let me know the solution.

Comment: Here are some suggestions to troubleshoot your situation

- Click on the debug icon. Look at the plans in both the cases. How is your utterance being interpreted? Which actions are being triggered? 
- Look at your training. Which of the utterances have the word recommendation and recommendations in them?

If this does not help, open a ticket with Bixby Support with all details (including your code).

Answer (score 1):

Plurals are not something that Bixby training will handle for you in general. You should add training for the plural forms if you expect the user will say such things.